# FileSystemWatcher not firing Events from Office file changes

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, filesystemwatcher

I'm trying to use a `FileSystemWatcher` to mirror two directories, but I've hit a hurdle with Office files. I don't seem to be able to get an event when a document/spreadsheet etc changes. This isn't to say that I'm not receiving any events however, as I understand the office apps frequently use temp files.

Here's an example of what I'm seeing, using the following code:

```
// Create the new watcher and hook up events
FileSystemWatcher fsw = new FileSystemWatcher(source);
fsw.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName | NotifyFilters.Attributes | NotifyFilters.Size | NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.CreationTime | NotifyFilters.Security;
fsw.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
fsw.InternalBufferSize = 64000;
fsw.Renamed += Fsw_Renamed;
fsw.Error += Fsw_Error;
fsw.Deleted += (o, e) => OnChange(pair, e);
fsw.Changed += (o, e) => OnChange(pair, e);
fsw.Created += (o, e) => OnChange(pair, e);
fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

The events that I see are as follows (using breakpoints in `onChange`, `Fsw_Error` and `Fsw_Renamed`):

> I create the word document

1. `Created` **New Microsoft Word Document.docx**
2. `Changed` **New Microsoft Word Document.docx**

> I open the word document

3. `Created` **~$w Microsoft Word Document.docx**
4. `Changed` **~$w Microsoft Word Document.docx**
5. `Changed` **~$w Microsoft Word Document.docx**

> I edit and then save the word document

6. `Created` **~WRD0000.tmp**

> I make more edits and then saves the word document

**No events...**

I really don't quite understand how this is working. The original `docx` file is being updated, but I'm not seeing any rename events or modifications. Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) indicates the [Filter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.filter(v=vs.110).aspx) property needs to be set

Even the example below the documentation seems to explicitly set the `Filter` property

Quoted from there

> To watch for changes in all files, set the Filter property to an empty string ("") or use wildcards ("*.*"). To watch a specific file, set the Filter property to the file name. For example, to watch for changes in the file MyDoc.txt, set the Filter property to "MyDoc.txt". You can also watch for changes in a certain type of file. For example, to watch for changes in text files, set the Filter property to "*.txt".

In your case you could try setting it to `*.docx`

### Update

From the comments below, its clear the above didnt work.

I wrote a simple console program like so

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var source = "D:\\temp\\folder";

        // Create the new watcher and hook up events
        var fsw = new FileSystemWatcher(source)
        {
            NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName | NotifyFilters.Attributes | NotifyFilters.Size | NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.CreationTime | NotifyFilters.Security,
            IncludeSubdirectories = true,
            InternalBufferSize = 64000
        };

        using (fsw)
        {
            fsw.Renamed += (o, e) => Console.WriteLine($"{e.OldFullPath} renamed to {e.FullPath}");
            fsw.Error += (o, e) => Console.WriteLine($"{e}");
            fsw.Deleted += (o, e) => Console.WriteLine($"{e.FullPath} deleted");
            fsw.Changed += (o, e) => Console.WriteLine($"{e.FullPath} changed");
            fsw.Created += (o, e) => Console.WriteLine($"{e.FullPath} created");
            fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

            Console.WriteLine("Ready. Press 'Q' to exit");
            while (Console.ReadKey().KeyChar != 'Q')
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

which produces the following output

#### at launch

```
Ready. Press 'Q' to exit
```

#### creating a new document

```
D:\temp\folder\Doc1.docx created
D:\temp\folder\Doc1.docx deleted
D:\temp\folder\Doc1.docx created
D:\temp\folder\~WRD0000.tmp created
D:\temp\folder\~WRD0000.tmp changed
D:\temp\folder\~WRD0000.tmp changed
D:\temp\folder\~WRD0000.tmp changed
D:\temp\folder\~WRD0000.tmp changed
D:\temp\folder\~WRD0000.tmp changed
D:\temp\folder\~WRD0000.tmp changed
D:\temp\folder\Doc1.docx renamed to D:\temp\folder\~WRL0001.tmp
D:\temp\folder\~WRD0000.tmp renamed to D:\temp\folder\Doc1.docx
D:\temp\folder\~WRL0001.tmp changed
D:\temp\folder\Doc1.docx changed
D:\temp\folder\Doc1.docx changed
D:\temp\folder\~WRL0001.tmp changed
D:\temp\folder\~$Doc1.docx created
D:\temp\folder\~$Doc1.docx changed
D:\temp\folder\~WRL0001.tmp deleted
```

#### editing the document

```
D:\temp\folder\~WRD0002.tmp created
D:\temp\folder\~WRD0002.tmp changed
D:\temp\folder\~WRD0002.tmp changed
D:\temp\folder\~WRD0002.tmp changed
D:\temp\folder\~WRD0002.tmp changed
D:\temp\folder\~WRD0002.tmp changed
D:\temp\folder\~WRD0002.tmp changed
D:\temp\folder\Doc1.docx renamed to D:\temp\folder\~WRL0003.tmp
D:\temp\folder\~WRD0002.tmp renamed to D:\temp\folder\Doc1.docx
D:\temp\folder\~WRL0003.tmp changed
D:\temp\folder\Doc1.docx changed
D:\temp\folder\Doc1.docx changed
D:\temp\folder\~WRL0003.tmp changed
D:\temp\folder\~WRL0003.tmp deleted
```

#### more edits

```
D:\temp\folder\~WRD0004.tmp created
D:\temp\folder\~WRD0004.tmp changed
D:\temp\folder\~WRD0004.tmp changed
D:\temp\folder\~WRD0004.tmp changed
D:\temp\folder\~WRD0004.tmp changed
D:\temp\folder\~WRD0004.tmp changed
D:\temp\folder\~WRD0004.tmp changed
D:\temp\folder\Doc1.docx renamed to D:\temp\folder\~WRL0005.tmp
D:\temp\folder\~WRD0004.tmp renamed to D:\temp\folder\Doc1.docx
D:\temp\folder\~WRL0005.tmp changed
D:\temp\folder\Doc1.docx changed
D:\temp\folder\Doc1.docx changed
D:\temp\folder\~WRL0005.tmp changed
D:\temp\folder\~WRL0005.tmp deleted
```

#### close word

```
D:\temp\folder\~$Doc1.docx deleted
```

#### delete from explorer

```
D:\temp\folder\Doc1.docx deleted
```

If you run this sample code and see similar (and expected) output like I did, 
you could modify your code to use this.

Comment: Having dug into this more, I think some of my other code must be at fault - specifically something I'm doing later with a ConcurrentQueue is somehow stopping me from receiving events from the FSW. I don't understand it as yet, but going to accept this as it clearly demonstrates how to use the FSW with office docs.